# Youtube Brand Manager API V3 Support

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I have a youtube channel, CNLohr, http://youtube.com/cnlohr which I use as my primary livestreaming platform.  It is distinct from my primary gmail account.  My gmail account has its own youtube, but I don't have subscribers or anything on that.  CNLohr is a "Brand manager"

My problem is that when authorizing an API application it seems to only apply to my gmail account account.  Even if I authorize it as my youtube brand.  It's very confusing as I can select my youtube or email account when at youtube but I cannot when visiting the API pages.

For example, if I visit https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list and attempt to use the "Try this API feature" it works flawlessly with my email account - however - there seems to be no way to log onto that site as "CNLohr."  When I click the icon up to, it only shows my gmail account and does not show my youtube account as an option.

No matter what I try I can't seem to get livestream or live stream chat IDs from my brand manager account, though it's trivial via my normal gmail account.

How should I proceed if I wish to use the youtube API with my primary 24k subscriber account?

[image: Comparing accounts]  (Scratched out just so no image screevers get my email, it's okay for you guys to know it!)

Comment: What is the account that you use for the user CNLohr? You said that your gmail account has its own youtube. So that means that you use other account for the user   CNLohr

Comment: CNLohr.  It is a brand manager account.  There is no email associated with that account.  It's just attached to my normal email account.   I have a youtube channel ID and a youtube user ID.  But, as soon as I log into youtube with my normal email, I can choose between my normal user and CNLohr.

Comment: I just edited my post to include a picture of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by youtube as of Jan, 2018.  Brands are now first-class citizens, and can perform the oauth as expected.