# YouTube API upload video to different YouTube accounts

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to find a way to publish videos to different youtube accounts. My client needs the customers to connect and authorize their youtube account and push videos to their channels.
I have currently done pushing videos to the account which i created the client id and secret as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) in the docs  but cannot push to other accounts.
my client is expecting a similar implementation as shown in the youtube video below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKNnPl0Zjiw

any help woud be much appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [Specify the channel to upload the videos in Youtube API using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62976250/8327971).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about it, I would assume you need to create a new connection to the YoutTubeAPI each time you want to publish something to a new channel, similar in a way you need to change accounts as shown in the video.

Basically, you could create a UI in which you can select different accounts. Whenever you change an account, you create a new connection to the API and login into the other account. This would be they way in which I would try and tackle the problem.