Unclear how to get Youtube OAUTH credentials for channel I have access to
I have been granted manager access to a channel by another user.  To accept the invite, I first had to create a channel (my personal channel) and then accept the invite.
In the Youtube UI, I can switch between my channel, and the channel I have access to.  I can also reply to comments on the channels videos as the channel (so the comments come from the channel's name).
I'm trying to do the same thing with the API.  I have some experience with using Google APIs (I have successfully used OAUTH2 to respond to Google My Business reviews).
I have been able to respond to comments on the channel videos via the API, but when I do, they come from my personal account name.  It appears I need to have an access token that is in the scope of the channel, but this is where I'm having trouble.
I have created my Google web client ID and consent page and enabled the Youtube APIs.  I then create the Auth URL using the oauth2 client.  I am passing in all of the youtube scopes:
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit",

I log in with the GMAIL that is also the one that has access to the channel.  I get all of the "warning, this APP will have access to your YOUTUBE" messages.  If I accept, then I get the callback and the access tokens, which I save the refresh token on the initial authorization, and use this to exchange for access tokens in the future.  This is also how I did it for Google Business using the business scopes.
When I use this token to reply to a comment on a video for the channel, it comes from my personal user, which makes sense.
I have read that the token needs to be scoped to the channel, rather than my gmail/personal youtube channel, but I don't get a selection asking me to pick a channel as I go through the auth process.
What step am I missing to get the access token with the scope of one of the channels I am managing?

When you authorize the app it should be asking you to pick a channel.  Its that Channel your access token will be associated with

Yes, that's what I would expect but it's not happening.  I found another comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350308/not-being-able-to-choose-the-right-channel-when-using-oauth-2-0-for-web-server-a that says it needs to be a brand channel or it won't work.  Will check into that today, my guess is that it is not a brand channel.

OK, so it was a brand account channel, but I was not an owner.  When the owner tried it, he was able to select the brand account (after picking his Gmail first) but then it's getting a "service restricted" error, trying to figure that out.  I've added only a single scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly for testing, still not working. Googling for "You tried to access a service that isn't available for your account" isn't turning up much.

Without your code its hard to help,  you should always include [example]

I've got it figured out.  Main issue was that I was a "manager" of a brand channel, and apparently this does not trigger the "brand account" selection screen.  I had the owner of the brand channel do the authentication and then it worked.  Didn't have to do with code in this case. Another tip is that even though I managed that account, the channels/list action with managedByMe flag is for something else.  That confused me.  As far as I can tell, each Brand Account has a single channel also, which is the "mine" channel and you need to auth for each individually.

Also, regarding the "service restricted" it was because I was trying to apply the Google Business scope and the Youtube scope against the Auth request.  You can apply both of those against a Gmail user, but you can't apply them both against a Brand account, that's why I was getting the error.  I had to create 2 separate auth channels, one for each.  So, auth with the youtube scope against the brand account (under a gmail) for youtube comments, and then against GMAIL top level for google my business.  If you add the youtube against a gmail first, then add the GMB, it still works also.

Make sure you anwser your own question it may help others in the future
